# Wireless adapter no longer showing up

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, vmware

How do I verify that the wireless driver is installed on Kali Linux (VMware Player). Kali is no longer showing the built-in wireless adapter using the iwconfig command but it can still connect to the internet wirelessly. This will prove to be an issue when trying to use Aircrack-ng. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: This question is asked (too) regularly here. You might find other answers.

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Most virtualization systems will share the physical host's network interfaces to the virtual machines as virtual plain old wired NICs. If both the host and the VM would have to take part in deciding which wireless network(s) to connect to, it would get a lot more complicated, and such a feature is very seldom needed.

If you want to use Kali Linux in a virtual machine, and use its Aircrack-ng or other wireless network penetration utilities, you'll need to have the physical host give full control of the wireless adapter to the virtual machine. This also means you cannot use the wireless networking from the host OS while the adapter control is handed over to the VM.

Handing over the control of an USB device is usually very easy: just select the right option in the VM control interface. But a built-in wireless adapter is quite likely PCI or PCIe-based, and that would require using a feature called PCI Passthrough. I'm not sure if VMware Player supports that feature; at least back in 2015, that feature was for the server-grade VMware ESXi only.

Comment: If your PC supports VT-d at least VMWare Fusion and Pro supports passthrough. ( VirtualBox, Parallels also do it) Mind you passthrough is not a perfect solution depending on the hw, functionality and performance needed. VMWare ESXi is the free version of a complex (corporate) solution. (You might have found a link from 2015 in which indeed at the time for private use only the ESXi WMware offering supported it...things have moved on). Should it not be USB passthrough?